# scipy.sparse.linalg: factorized() vs SuperLU

Tags: python-3.x, математика, numpy, scipy, линейная-алгебра

В чем разница между

```py
 scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized(A)
```

и

```py
 scipy.sparse.linalg.splu(A)
```

Обе функции возвращают объект с методом `.solve(rhs)` и для обоих в документации сказано, что используется LU-разложение матрицы. Хотел бы узнать, чем они отличаются, как в плане алгоритма, так и в  плане производительности.

Если подробнее, то я пишу МКЭ модель с использованием python/numpy/scipy. Мне нужно решать уравнение `Au = f` на каждом шаге по времени. A матрица большой размерности, но разреженная и не зависит от времени, так что я хотел бы делать какие-то предварительные действия с А, чтобы ускорить итерации (их может быть несколько тысяч, если расчет долгий). Я пробовал использовать `scipy.sparse.linalg.inv(A)`, но получал memory exceptions при большом числе узлов сетки. До недавнего момента использовал `scipy.linalg.spsolve` на каждом шаге, сейчас думаю применить какое-нибудь разложение, чтобы ускорить итерации. Если у вас есть какие-то предложения помимо LU-разложения, буду рад услышать.

Comment: [Этот вопрос на английском SO с ответом и дельным комментарием](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57239217/2452869)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scipy.sparse.linalg.splu()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.splu) - вычисляет LU-разложение разреженной матрицы **с помощью библиотеки [SuperLU](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/)**. Это эффективный и достаточно гибкий способ решить разреженную систему линейных уравнений прямым (неитеративным) способом.

[`scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized.html) - тоже вычисляет LU-разложение разреженной матрицы, однако **конкретный метод для вычисление не определен**. В частности, если установить с помощью [`scipy.sparse.linalg.use_solver`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.use_solver.html) параметр `useUmfpack`, то для разложения будет использоваться [UMFPACK](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html). По состоянию на данный момент, `useUmfpack==True` по умолчанию, если UMFPACK подключен к SciPy. В будущем, вполне могут появиться дополнительные опции.

Исходя из этого, если на вашей системе установлен UMFPACK в SciPy, то `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu()` и `scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized()` будут использовать разные библиотеки для разложение разреженной матрицы `A`.

Исходя из моего опыта, UMFPACK показывает лучшую производительность чем SuperLU при полных разложениях разреженных матриц (ваш случай). Однако, при использовании неполных разложений (для предобуславливателей-preconditioners) - ILU (incomplete LU) - SuperLU был предпочтительней (см, [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html)). Моя область применения была заточена под матрицы происходящие из различных задач вычислительного электромагнетизма: дифференциальных и интегральных формулировок.

В вашем случае, я бы попробовал оба варианта, но все же склонился к тому, чтобы заморочиться с UMFPACK. Многое зависит от настроек и конкретных свойств системы, которую вы пытаетесь решить.